# sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds into a table [How2]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Im looking to making a job that will tell me the number of pending cmd's on the replication,
Im using sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds and im trying my best to put it into a table.

But im keep getting the error 
`An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.`
any ideas how to do it ?
Im open to suggestions

Thank You

I've tried :

```
DECLARE @tab AS TABLE (pendingcmds int, estimatedprocesstime int) 

INSERT into @tab EXECUTE  sp_executesql N'exec sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds   @publisher=[AUTOSQL1\COMPLOT],  
@publisher_db=PTK_M,  @publication=PTK_M_1way,  
@subscriber=[COMPLOTSQL2008\REPL],  @subscriber_db=
PTK_M,  @subscription_type=0'
  SELECT * FROM @tab

insert pendingcmds   (pendingcmdcount ,estimatedprocesstime) 
execute sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds   
@publisher=[AUTOSQL1\COMPLOT],  @publisher_db=PTK_M,  
@publication=PTK_M_1way,  @subscriber=[COMPLOTSQL2008\REPL],  
@subscriber_db=PTK_M,  @subscription_type=0
into pendingcmds   (pendingcmdcount ,estimatedprocesstime)

declare @v nvarchar (max)
set @v=N'exec sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds   @publisher=[AUTOSQL1\COMPLOT],  
@publisher_db=PTK_M,  @publication=PTK_M_1way,  
@subscriber=[COMPLOTSQL2008\REPL],  @subscriber_db=
PTK_M,  @subscription_type=0'
print @v
INSERT INTO pendingcmds (pendingcmdcount,estimatedprocesstime)
exec sp_executesql @v
```

Answer (score 2):

sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds calls the below internally which is being seen by SQL Server as a nested insert.

```
insert into @countab (pendingcmdcount)
exec @retcode = sys.sp_MSget_repl_commands 
                @agent_id = @agent_id,
                @last_xact_seqno = @xact_seqno,
                @get_count = 2,
                @compatibility_level = 9000000
```

Here is a good blog on a workaround: [SimpleTalk Monitoring Transactional Replication in SQL Server by Francis Hanlon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/monitoring-transactional-replication-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have exactly what you need.

it is a bit of a long script but if you use the replication (transactional) it can be useful.

It assumes that your distribution database is called `distribution` - I have servers with more than one distribution database, so you need to specify its name.

this script is to be run at the distributor, or publisher (if it is configured as the distributor too) basically wherever you `distribution` database lives.

check it out:

```
        --====================================================================================
        -- I got this script from Mohammed Mawla - all glories to him!
        -- I did some changes
        -- it works in most of my servers, as long permissions are granted on both the publisher and distributor
        -- I get sometimes errors like these:

        -- publisher server name is encrypted or distributor server does not have right to access the publisher
        -- Msg 20032, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds, Line 52 [Batch Start Line 23]
        -- '[28D09263-3FCA-42F2-86FD-1C9C7CA3951A]' is not defined as a Subscriber for 'SQLPROD1'.

        -- Marcello Miorelli
        -- 30-dec-2019
        --====================================================================================

Use Master;
GO
Set NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO

IF object_id('tempdb..#Radhe_sub2') is not null
   DROP TABLE #Radhe_sub2

IF object_id('tempdb..#Radhe_sub1') is not null
   DROP TABLE #Radhe_sub1

Create TABLE #Radhe_sub2 ( publisher SYSNAME 
                        , publisher_db SYSNAME
                        , publication SYSNAME
                        , subscriber SYSNAME
                        , subscriber_db SYSNAME
                        , Pending_Commands int 
                        , time_to_deliver_pending_Commands int)

DECLARE 
  @publisher SYSNAME
, @publisher_db SYSNAME
, @publication SYSNAME
, @subscriber SYSNAME
, @subscriber_db SYSNAME

SELECT
sub3.publisher
,sub1.publisher_db
,sub1.publication
,CASE when sub1.anonymous_subid is not null then upper(sub1.subscriber_name) ELSE UPPER (srv.name) END 'Subscriber'
,sub1.subscriber_db
,Sub1.job_id,sub1.id
,subscription_type
,sub1.name
into #Radhe_sub1
FROM
(
SELECT * 
  FROM distribution..msdistribution_agents agents
 Where subscriber_db not in ('virtual') -- Don't retrieve Virtual subscriptions
   and anonymous_subid is null -- Don't retrieve anonymous subscriptions

) sub1
Inner join
(
SELECT
publisher
,publisher_db
,publication
,publication_type
,agent_name
,publisher_srvid
,job_id
FROM distribution..MSreplication_monitordata
WHERE publication_id is not null
AND agent_type = 3 -- Distribution agent
)sub3

on sub1.publisher_id = sub3.publisher_srvid
and cast(sub1.job_id as uniqueidentifier) = sub3.job_id
and sub1.publisher_db=sub3.publisher_db
and sub1.publication= sub3.publication
and sub1.subscription_type=sub3.publication_type
and sub1.name =sub3.agent_name
join master.sys.servers as srv
on srv.server_id = sub1.subscriber_id

DECLARE subscribers cursor READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD for 
SELECT 
  publisher
, publisher_db 
, publication 
, subscriber 
, subscriber_db 
from #Radhe_sub1

OPEN subscribers FETCH NEXT FROM subscribers INTO @publisher
, @publisher_db 
, @publication 
, @subscriber 
, @subscriber_db

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

--select @subscriber = N'CTDB01'

--begin try
        INSERT into #Radhe_sub2
        EXEC
        (
        '
        SELECT '''+ @publisher +''' 
                , '''+ @publisher_db +''' 
                ,'''+ @publication + ''' 
                , ''' + @subscriber + ''' 
                , ''' + @subscriber_db + ''' 
                ,*
                        FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB''
                ,''Server='+@@servername+';TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''
                ,''set fmtonly off EXEC distribution..sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpENDingcmds @publisher= '''''+ @publisher +''''' 
                ,@subscription_type=0
                , @publisher_db= '''''+ @publisher_db +'''''
                ,@publication = '''''+ @publication+'''''
                ,@subscriber= '''''+@subscriber+''''' 
                ,@subscriber_db='''''+@subscriber_db+''''''')
        '

        --====================================================================================
        -- the problem with this line below is that it does not work with named instances Server=(local)
        --'
        --SELECT '''+ @publisher +''' 
        --, '''+ @publisher_db +''' 
        --,'''+ @publication + ''' 
        --, ''' + @subscriber + ''' 
        --, ''' + @subscriber_db + ''' 
        --,*
        --  FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB''
        --,''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''
        --,''set fmtonly off EXEC distribution..sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpENDingcmds @publisher= '''''+ @publisher +''''' 
        --,@subscription_type=0
        --, @publisher_db= '''''+ @publisher_db +'''''
        --,@publication = '''''+ @publication+'''''
        --,@subscriber= '''''+@subscriber+''''' 
        --,@subscriber_db='''''+@subscriber_db+''''''')
        --'
        --====================================================================================

        )
--end try
--begin catch
--end catch


FETCH NEXT 
FROM subscribers 
INTO 
 @publisher
,@publisher_db 
,@publication 
,@subscriber 
,@subscriber_db

END

CLOSE subscribers DEALLOCATE subscribers

SELECT
Pending_commands.*
,comment.comments
,comment.delivery_latency 'Delivery_latency MSs'
,comment.time 'Time of message'
,CASE comment.runstatus
when 1 then 'Started'
when 2 then 'Succeeded'
when 3 then 'In progress'
when 4 then 'Idle'
when 5 then 'Retrying'
when 6 then 'Failed ' END status ,

CASE Info.subscription_type When 0 then 'Push' When 1 then 'Pull' When 2 then 'Anonymous' END 'Subscription Type'
,Info.name 'Distribution agent name'
,jobs.name 'Distribution_agent_job'

FROM

#Radhe_sub1 Info

inner join

#Radhe_sub2 PENDing_commands

on Info.publisher_db = PENDing_commands.publisher_db
and Info.publication = PENDing_commands.publication
and Info.subscriber = PENDing_commands.subscriber
and Info.subscriber_db = PENDing_commands.subscriber_db

left outer join msdb..sysjobs jobs

on Info.job_id=jobs.job_id

inner join
(
SELECT time
, agent_id 
,runstatus
,delivery_latency
, comments
,row_number() over ( partition by agent_id order by time desc ) as pos

FROM distribution..MSdistribution_history
)comment

on comment.agent_id = Info.id

where comment.pos =1 ;
GO
```

Answer (score -2):

Since your table/schema is already known, try like this way.

Instead of a table type variable like what you have already done

```
DECLARE @tab AS TABLE (pendingcmds int, estimatedprocesstime int)
```

Create a temporary table and then insert your data there, like

```
CREATE TABLE #tab (pendingcmds int, estimatedprocesstime int)
```

Then do the insertion, like

```
INSERT into #tab(pendingcmds,estimatedprocesstime) 
EXEC sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds   @publisher=[AUTOSQL1\COMPLOT],  
@publisher_db=PTK_M,  @publication=PTK_M_1way,  
@subscriber=[COMPLOTSQL2008\REPL],  @subscriber_db=
PTK_M,  @subscription_type=0'
```

Select the values

```
SELECT * FROM #tab
```

Comment: Nope still no good.
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Comment: This can never work because of an internal insert within the sproc.